# Can one piecewise function have two metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers, metric-spaces, low-dimensional-topology

Can one make a piecewise function on the manifold of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}^1$ that works on two metric spaces? A metric space is a set together with a metric, a means to tell the distance between two points. One is familiar with piecewise functions being discontinuous between the pieces. One could decide to pick different metric/distance functions for each piece function. Consider this simple two-part function:

$$ f(z) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f_1 = z/|z| & \rm{if \;Re}(z) = 0\; and\; Im(z) \ne 0 \\
            f_2 = (\cosh(Re(z)), \sinh(Re(z)) & 
        \end{array} 
    \right. $$

The first function $f_1$ has a metric function of a norm, $z=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. The norm is zero or a positive number. Because the square of the second function $f_2$ is equal to positive one, a square could serve as a metric function (the way one measures distance), $z=a^2-b^2$. A square is a signed measure since it can be negative.

Comment: None of what you wrote is clear.

Comment: I shifted the question to be about two metric spaces for one piecewise complex-valued function in an effort to be more clear. Perhaps I should drop references to $f_3$ as it might just be confusing.

Comment: What does it mean for a function to have a metric space? And what do you mean when you define a function as an equation involving that very function (where that equation doesn't fix the function either)?

Comment: Many (if not most) concepts used in your question are undefined: "piece has a different measure function", "function has a metric space", "measure function of a norm", "square could serve as a metric function."

Comment: The piecewise function was made more explicit. The two metric functions were written out explicitly.

Comment: OK, now the definition of the function makes a bit more sense, although it is not defined at $z=0$, and I'm not sure how to interpret $f_2$ (my best guess from the formula would be that you mean the complex number $\cosh(\operatorname{Re}(z)) + \mathrm i\sinh(\operatorname{Re}(z))$, but that would not square to $1$). I also still can't figure out what you mean with the function having a metric.

Comment: The last two sentences "Because the square of the second function $f_2$ is equal to positive one, a square could serve as a metric function (the way one measures distance), $z=a^2-b^2$. A square is a signed measure since it can be negative." are still unclear. As a general remark, you can put any metric you like on the given set, nobody is stopping you.

Comment: The "if" clause was modified so for the case of $z=0$ the function would evaluate to $(1, 0)$, and its square is $(1, 0)$.

Comment: I have a specific motivation for this question, but it would require far much too detail to explain, so I accept the last two sentences are unclear. My question is in terms of standard notation, how would I most efficiently communicate that for the set formed from the range of $f_1$, I had chosen the metric $z=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, and for the set formed from the range of $f_2$, I had chosen the metric $z=a^2-b^2$?

Comment: In which sense is $z=a^2-b^2$ a metric? To begin with, what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $z = a + b i$. $z = a^2 - b^2$ is a signed metric, meaning it can evaluate to a negative number as it will when $b > a$.

Comment: As you mention youself, a metric provides "a means to tell the distance between **_two_** points". (emphasis added) It's not clear what you mean by a function having a metric function.  Are you trying to say the function defines a metric? Then it should have _two_ inputs from your set. You do not have that. Furthermore a distance should be real valued, but your $f_1$ is always imaginary since Re(z)=0 for that part; and assuming you mean $f_2 = \cosh(Re(z)) + i\ \sinh(Re(z))$, then this would always be complex valued since Re(z)!=0 for that piece.

Comment: It feels like you are trying to use math terms that are beyond your current understanding, to try to be more precise for us. If this is the case, please do not reach like this. It actually makes it harder for us to understand because those terms you are jumbling together have a specific meaning, and the way you are using them is causing more confusion.  Ask the question you actually want to ask using simpler math terms.

Comment: I'm guessing the input to your function is a single complex value. What is the output? A complex value, or maybe the output is an actual function? What do you want to measure distance between? Why is that not a separate function? Are you trying to say you want the output to be in some space where you forbid asking the distance between a complex value with real part zero and a complex value with non-zero real part? That sounds weird, but that would be a property of the output space (the _codomain_), not "The first function f1 has a metric function of a norm" which no-one understands.

Comment: dwb1: It is non-sense to say "a function [has] a metric function". That was in my original post, but it cannot be defended. Instead, one can talk about the set formed from the range of a function and a specific metric can form a metric space. I have two sets created by two functions and two metrics, so two metric spaces. The function $f_1$ will be entirely imaginary, and so the distance between zero and any particular point will be $\sqrt{0^2 + 1^2} = 1$. The function $f_2$ is equal to the real value of unity when $z=0$, otherwise you are correct.

Comment: dwb2: I prefer to work numerically. I created a real-valued quaternion function that can do rotations and boosts, demonstrating that 40k points count be rotated, and 40k points could be boosted. I have argued since June of 2019 with someone online that my numerical observation cannot be true. The domain of a quaternion manifold has four degrees of freedom. The continuous Lorentz group has a discrete Lie algebra that has 6 degrees of freedom. Since 6 degrees of freedom is greater than 4, it is not possible. An app to demonstrate rotations failed, https://rotations-only.herokuapp.com/.

Comment: dwb3: I specialize in using quaternions. For broader discussions, it is far easier to talk about a subgroup of quaternions, the complex numbers. There is one piecewise function that takes a quaternion to be transformed, a quaternion parameter, and outputs a single quaternion that has been rotated and/or boosted. The codomain of $f_1$ with the function $z=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ forms one metric space, the codomain of $f_2$ with the function $z=a^2-b^2$ forms a second, independent metric space.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not clear what you are asking. Yes the Lorentz group is 6 dimensional, and it can be viewed as linear maps acting on a 4 dimensional space. That is not a contradiction. And there are not multiple parts of that space with different metrics attached to it. In my opinion, it sounds like you think you have narrowed in on a core piece of some larger question you actually care about, when in reality it sounds like you've mistaken something somewhere and are getting side tracked by something you think demands some concept of piecewise metric spaces.

Comment: Just ask your actual question. Whatever is going on, you are not doing yourself a favor here by trying to summarize the actual question, since it sounds like the summarizing to what you feel is a core question is itself flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive clarification, it sounds like the question can be broken down as follows:

#### Part 1:  Can the codomain of a function be the union of two different metric spaces?

Sure. It is unclear how this would come up naturally, but if there are two metric spaces $A$ and $B$, then it is possible to define some function $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow (A \cup B)$.

#### Part 2: How could one clearly mark this in a piecewise function, if the underlying sets of $A$ and $B$ are the same?

I'd be curious to see other people's suggestions, but here is a possible solution:

$$f(z) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
z/|z| \in A & \text{if Re}(z) = 0 \text{ and Im}(z) \ne 0 \\
\cosh(\text{Re}(z)) + i \sinh(\text{Re}(z)) \in B & \text{if Re}(z) \ne 0 \text{ or } z = 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

Alternatively, to make this more explicit one could use a [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union), sometimes called a "tagged union". For example if we have multiple metric spaces $M_i$, we could define a disjoint union
$$D = \bigcup_i \{(x,i) : x \in M_i \}.$$
Then we could define a function $g : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow D$.

In your case, the function could be defined as:

$$
\begin{aligned}
g &: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \left( \{(z,0) : z \in A\} \cup \{(z,1) : z \in B\} \right) \\
g(z) &=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
(z/|z|,\ 0) & \text{if Re}(z) = 0 \text{ and Im}(z) \ne 0 \\
(\cosh(\text{Re}(z)) + i \sinh(\text{Re}(z)),\ 1) & \text{if Re}(z) \ne 0 \text{ or } z = 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right.
\end{aligned}
$$

You could in principle just tag with the set itself, so you might prefer this (I am not sure how common this is, but the meaning should still be clear):

$$
\begin{aligned}
h &: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \left( \{(z,A) : z \in A\} \cup \{(z,B) : z \in B\} \right) \\
h(z) &=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
(z/|z|,\ A) & \text{if Re}(z) = 0 \text{ and Im}(z) \ne 0 \\
(\cosh(\text{Re}(z)) + i \sinh(\text{Re}(z)),\ B) & \text{if Re}(z) \ne 0 \text{ or } z = 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Where should the explicit metric function for A and B go in the answer? Possible example: $d_A(p, q) = Re(p^* q)$, $d_B(p, q) = Re(p q)$. For $f(z)$, $d_A(p, p) = 1$, $d_B(p, p) = 1$.

Comment: @sweetser If you want to explicitly state what the two metric spaces are, there is nothing preventing you, but it should be done independently of defining this function. Otherwise it leads to confusion how these objects are related in your discussion.

Comment: As an aside, your distance functions make no sense. Any point should always be 0 distance from itself. This is usually one of the required defining properties of a distance function.

Comment: I've still seen nothing convincing that you need some bizarre concept of a split metric space in the first place. It looks like all you really want is to be able to say the output of your function is normalized in some sense. It appears that sense is, the output has the property $Re(f(z)f(z))^2 = 1$. Just say that. It is true for both pieces. There is no need to wander into metric spaces, and make up bizarre concepts of split metric spaces.

Comment: My first ever effort at writing a metric function was in error. This may be better: $d_A(p, q) = Re((p - q)^* (p - q))$ and signed metric function $d_B(p, q) = Re((p - q)^2) $. In a context not detailed here, the first codomain is used for standard rotations in space. The second codomain is the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry, a metric space of velocities used in special relativity.